# Is there a way to protect email using passcode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I dont want to put passcode on phone, it is quite annoying, i just want to protect email. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419382/219555, you can use Spark iOS client that has this feature (passcode/FaceID/TouchID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to jailbreak your iPhone to password-protect the Mail app. Sorry, there's no other way. :-)

I ran across [this article](http://www.thedailybuggle.com/password-protect-apps-iphone-ipod-touch-ipad/), which has three apps for password protecting iOS apps.

- Lockdown Pro
- FolderLock
- Locktopus

All are paid apps.

[This article](http://iphonemonsta.com/iapplocker-free-password-protect-iphone-ipad-ios-apps-cydia-tweak) mentions an app called iAppLocker. It is free. Hope this helps you!

Comment: do you know of any such app? I've jail broken it...

Comment: @EternalNoob I've edited my question.

Comment: @EternalNoob Yeah, no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Use a web based email client via Safari, and log out when not using it.

Answer (score 2):

forward all the mail adresses you want to see on you iphone to a single gmail account. get the gmail application the second one in the store, the blue one. set it up to access that account. Now you can remove the email account in the email section of your phone. When you want to do mail, sign into the gmail app, and sign back out when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreaking, no. You cannot in the standard Mail app, and I know of no other iOS mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

[Boxer App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boxer-for-gmail-outlook-exchange/id561712083?mt=8) does this. It has a free and a paid version.

Unfortunately, in my experience, it's a bit buggy, and it doesn't support Textexpander Touch snippets. However it's probably worth trying, if a passcode is important to you.