# Does anybody know an email client for iOS that is password protected?

Tags: ios, email, security

I am looking for an email client, that when opened, asks for a password before showing email messages. Is there such an app available for iOS?

Comment: Do you also need ut to log out when you leave your computer? and could you set the screen saver to need a password before unlocking?

Comment: What screen saver? This is an iOS device.

Comment: Great question. I've been wondering the same thing. Hopefully Apple makes this option native soon.

Comment: Just an idea that crossed my mind, please ignore if you've tried it. I wonder if encrypting the executable within the mail application would do the trick so that it can not be opened without inputing some passphrase. I thought of changing permissions, but maybe you need to change them back again after permission repairs.

Comment: So ridiculous that such an app is so hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen an app like that, but if you have a Gmail account you can use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/ios) ([App Store Link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/1password-password-manager/id568903335?ls=1&mt=8)) to access the web interface. The 1Password app is locked by default. This would work with any email account with a webmail interface.

Comment: I don't mind down votes, if they are warranted. How would you improve or rewrite this answer?

Comment: No idea. It's a good workaround, in my opinion. +1

Comment: I like your idea so up voting you. The only thing I can think of why someone may have down voted you is a browser may not be considered a mail client

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Question asks for an email client, not an html browser. This is more of a work-around *IF* your provider happens to have a good mobile front end...

Comment: Gmail tries incredibly hard to link to devices, making access to the phone a large step toward being able to gain access to an account that isn't yours. Seems a sound workaround otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

**Spark** client for iOS has ability to set passcode or use FaceID/TouchID.

Check **Hamburger Menu->Settings->Security**

[Link to App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/spark-mail-email-by-readdle/id997102246)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server are you accessing? If you use Exchange, check out [Mail+ for Outlook](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mail+-for-outlook/id428974099?mt=8). They have an easy to set passcode option which prompts you for a pin each time the app is launched. If you do not successfully provide the passcode within 5 attempts, your credentials and all emails are erased.

If you are using ActiveSync (or have ActiveSync for Gmail), check out their other version. It uses similar technology.

Answer (score 0):

[Boxer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boxer-for-gmail-outlook-exchange/id561712083?mt=8) does this. There is a free and a paid version.

Unfortunatley it is, in my experience, buggy, and it doesn't support text expander touch. I'm still on the lookout for the perfect mail app.

Comment: This app seems no longer available. Do you know if it was renamed or replaced, etc.?

Comment: I haven't used it for many years, but a quick search revealed this: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/boxer-workspace-one/id1087506559

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Exchange ActiveSync - check out NitroDesk Touchdown for iOS. I've a feeling that has a passcode screen on launch/switch.

Comment: This appears to be called *Symantec TouchDown* now. Still not really sure what it even is...